# How do I remove a URL from Google without having to have a Google E-mail Account

Tags: google, url

Really simple question. I do not want a Google account. I just want Google to stop making requests every 2 minutes for a URL it should never have known about (apparently Google harvests URLs from search requests as well as private e-mails, not just from actual web pages).

But when I search Google help for removing URLs it appears I have to use their "webmaster tools" which require logging into a GMail account!

How do I tell Google not to index my URL without becoming a customer?

Note: I already return 404 for the URLs in question using a rewrite rule - this appears to make zero difference to the crawler which continually attempts to fetch the page every 2 minutes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a GMail account, just a Google website account - you can use your existing email to log in to a Google account same as any other website's login.

Go here to [set up a Google Account that authenticates with your current email](https://www.google.com/accounts/NewAccount).

Comment: I didn't realise you could use a different e-mail, maybe even mailinator.com would be sufficient..

Answer (score 8):

Setup a [robots.txt](http://www.robotstxt.org/) file to block things from search engines.

Comment: +1 ... surprising how many anti-search-engine people don't know about robots.txt yet.

Answer (score 1):

don't allow robots to index it. Try:

```
<meta name="ROBOTS" content="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW, NOARCHIVE, NOSNIPPET, NOODP, NOYDIR" />
```

in the head of the page.

Comment: I don't think he wants google to hit the page in the first place.  Setting a meta tag on the page means Google will hit it at least once.  A robots.txt seems like a better option.